# Windmove-mode: S-up and S-down becomes text selection instead of switching windows

Tags: window, osx

I enabled windmove by running `m-x  windmove-default-keybindings`.

S-left and S-right work as expected when two windows are side by side.

However when  a frame is splitted vertically, I cannot use S-up/S-down to switch between top and bottom window.  Instead they become text selection (much like ctrl-space)

How can I fix this key bindings? Why `windmove-default-keybindings` cannot set them?

Emacs version: GNU Emacs 24.5.1

Comment: `windmove` would have set those bindings. (I am saying that with a grain of salt as I don't have osx. I can say for sure that the bindings work on linux.) But then something else later in your config overrode those bindings. What do you see when you do `C-h k` followed by pressing `S-up`?

Comment: Are you running it in the terminal? Does disabling [shift selection mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shift-Selection.html) fix the windmove keybindings?

Comment: (Sounds like a bug.) Have you tried contacting the windmove.el author?

Comment: Are you still using Aquamacs and combining that with Ergoemacs -- if so, you may wish to update your question with some additional details regarding your customized setup.  Most of the forum participants will not be using either, but those details may directly relate to your issue.

Comment: @lawlist No. It is GNU Emacs 24.5.1 on Terminal

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that `shift-select-mode` is set to `nil`.

Documentation:
When non-nil, shifted motion keys activate the mark momentarily.

While the mark is activated in this way, any shift-translated point
motion key extends the region, and if Transient Mark mode was off, it
is temporarily turned on.  Furthermore, the mark will be deactivated
by any subsequent point motion key that was not shift-translated, or
by any action that normally deactivates the mark in Transient Mark mode.

Comment: `shift-select-mode` is `t` for me (default) and still all the `windmove` bindings work fine for me. Emacs 25.x on RHEL 5.10.