# windmove doesn't recognize S-<up> and S-<down> on Macbook Terminal

Tags: key-bindings, window, shift-selection

GNU Emacs 27.2 in Mac OS terminal (11.4 Big Sur).

Started with

```
(windmove-default-keybindings)
```

and found that `S-<up>` and `S-<down>` behaved just as `<up>` and `<down>`, as if the shift is not detected, whereas `S-<left>` and `S-<right>` behaved as expected.

Tried

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "S-<up>") 'windmove-up)
(define-key global-map (kbd "S-<down>") 'windmove-down)
```

and there was no change in behavior.

Saw this: [Windmove-mode: S-up and S-down becomes text selection instead of switching windows](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13178/) and tried adding

```
(setq shift-select-mode nil)
```

(even though `S-<up>` and `S-<down>` were not acting to select), and again, no change in behavior. `windmove` works correctly with `S-<up>` and `S-<down>`, but not for `S-<left>` and `S-<right>`.

Complete, minimal `.emacs` file:

```
; (windmove-default-keybindings)
(define-key global-map (kbd "S-<up>") 'windmove-up)
(define-key global-map (kbd "S-<down>") 'windmove-down)
(define-key global-map (kbd "S-<left>") 'windmove-left)
(define-key global-map (kbd "S-<right>") 'windmove-right)

(setq inhibit-startup-message t)
(load-theme 'wombat)
(menu-bar-mode -1)
```

Comment: Use iterm2 not the default terminal program.

Comment: @FranklinHerman The default terminal is configurable as well, with a very similar interface. iTerm2 is almost identical in this respect, its only advantage is that it knows a few more key chords by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs running in the terminal can’t receive a lot of key combinations. Shifted arrow keys are just one more example in a long list. Run the Emacs gui instead.

You can see this in action by using `C-h k`, then pressing a key combination. Emacs will tell you what it received and what command it would invoke.

Comment: That depends on the terminal. The macOS Terminal application doesn't distinguish Shift+{Up,Down} from {Up,Down} by default, but it can easily made to.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal emulators (and hardware terminals) send escape sequences for key chords involving cursor keys or function keys. Only a few key chords have widely accepted standard escape sequences, and many terminals ignore certain modifiers. In particular, the macOS Terminal application sends the same escape sequence for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> as for <kbd>Up</kbd>, so Emacs has no way to distinguish between the two. See [Shift+Up isn't recognized by Emacs in a terminal](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/977/shiftup-isnt-recognized-by-emacs-in-a-terminal/989#989) and [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal/13957#13957) for more background.

You can change escape sequences in the Terminal preferences, under the “Keyboard” tab of each profile. Choose <kbd>Up</kbd> as the key, <kbd>Shift</kbd> as the modifier combination, “Send Text:” as the action and `\033[1;2A` as the text. (`\033` stands for an escape character, which can also be shown as `ESC` or `^[` in other contexts.) This is a standard encoding of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> which Emacs recognizes out of the box. For <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, use `\033[1;2B` as the text. If you want other modifier combinations, use `1;5` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and `1;6` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. <kbd>Left</kbd> is `C` and <kbd>Right</kbd> is `D`. Terminal supports {<kbd>Shift</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>}+{<kbd>Left</kbd>,<kbd>Right</kbd>} out of the box.